# Slime-repl isn't here

Tags: macos, emacs, lisp, slime, sbcl

I have installed Emacs + SBCL + slime but I have a problem with slime.
I'm on a Mac OS X 10.7.4

When I do M-x slime I have two screen *scratch* on the top and *inferior-lisp* on the bottom.
But I don't have *slime-repl*
What kind of information you need to know to find where is the source of the problem.

Here is the message in the *inferior-lisp* at the begining :

```
(progn (load "/opt/local/slime/swank-loader.lisp" :verbose t) (funcall (read-from-string "swank-loader:init")) (funcall (read-from-string "swank:start-server") "/var/folders/4x/t_tmqdjs0jbbj_52bz2yy1xr0000gn/T/slime.14914"))

This is SBCL 1.0.55.0-abb03f9, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
* 
; loading #P"/opt/local/slime/swank-loader.lisp"
; loading #P"/Users/guillaume/.slime/fasl/2012-09-04/sbcl-1.0.55.0-abb03f9-no-threads-darwin-x86/swank-backend.fasl"
; loading #P"/Users/guillaume/.slime/fasl/2012-09-04/sbcl-1.0.55.0-abb03f9-no-threads-darwin-x86/swank-source-path-parser.fasl"
; loading #P"/Users/guillaume/.slime/fasl/2012-09-04/sbcl-1.0.55.0-abb03f9-no-threads-darwin-x86/swank-source-file-cache.fasl"
; loading #P"/Users/guillaume/.slime/fasl/2012-09-04/sbcl-1.0.55.0-abb03f9-no-threads-darwin-x86/swank-sbcl.fasl"
STYLE-WARNING: redefining EMACS-INSPECT (#<BUILT-IN-CLASS T>) in DEFMETHOD
; loading #P"/Users/guillaume/.slime/fasl/2012-09-04/sbcl-1.0.55.0-abb03f9-no-threads-darwin-x86/swank-gray.fasl"
STYLE-WARNING:
   Implicitly creating new generic function STREAM-READ-CHAR-WILL-HANG-P.
; loading #P"/Users/guillaume/.slime/fasl/2012-09-04/sbcl-1.0.55.0-abb03f9-no-threads-darwin-x86/swank-match.fasl"
; loading #P"/Users/guillaume/.slime/fasl/2012-09-04/sbcl-1.0.55.0-abb03f9-no-threads-darwin-x86/swank-rpc.fasl"
; loading #P"/Users/guillaume/.slime/fasl/2012-09-04/sbcl-1.0.55.0-abb03f9-no-threads-darwin-x86/swank.fasl"
WARNING: These Swank interfaces are unimplemented:
 (DISASSEMBLE-FRAME INTERRUPT-THREAD RECEIVE-IF SLDB-BREAK-AT-START
  SLDB-BREAK-ON-RETURN SPAWN)
;; Swank started at port: 57792.
57792
```

Comment: Here is the list of my buffer : *inferior-lisp* , *Compile-Log*  , *slime-events* , *scratch*  , *Messages*

Comment: Here is my * slime-events * buffer : 
`provides-putwc :os-provides-dladdr :os-provides-dlopen ...)
        :modules`
        ("SB-CLTL2" "SB-POSIX" "SB-INTROSPECT" "SB-BSD-SOCKETS" "SB-GROVEL" "ASDF")
        :package
        (:name "COMMON-LISP-USER" :prompt "CL-USER")
        :version "2012-09-04"))
 1)`

Comment: And i don't have the M-x slime-to-output-buffer , I can't execute it

Comment: Yes I was the problem because I installed a specific version first.
Today I install the official slime but I didn't remove some line on the emacs.d/init.el so I remove some line and now It's good. I have my * inferior-slime * and my * scratch *
So now I think it's good :)
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Slime-repl doesn't show up unless its enabled in the slime setup.

```
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))
```